# Proper way to catch KeyError in Django?

Tags: django, url, key

I am creating an API where a URL is sent to the server.  I want to get the username, etc from the URL.  I use the following code to do that:

```
 try:
    username = request.REQUEST['username']
    message  = request.REQUEST['message']
    time = request.REQUEST['time']

 except KeyError:
    ...
```

However, there are times when the URL does not have a username, message, time, etc in it.  In that case, a KeyError is raised.  I want to be able to catch this and know which parameter was missing so I can issue an error response code that tells the user which parameter was missing.  In the except area, is there a way to determine where the code failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not cleanly. Use a default of `None` and test after.

```
try:
  username = request.REQUEST.get('username', None)
   ...
except ...:
   ...
else:
  if username is None:
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't this work? No need for exceptions

```
if 'username' in request.REQUEST:
    username = request.REQUEST['username']
else:
    #username not found
```

Comment: how about for object oriented?